# Apply new array of disabled dates on the monthChange event of the bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I'm using [this date picker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

I have this code:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off"
       class="aDatePicker"
       id="new-date" name="date">


<script>
    var disabled_dates = ['08/12/2016','08/13/2016','08/14/2016'];

    $(function () {
        applyDatePickerToElement();

        function applyDatePickerToElement() {
            $('.aDatePicker').datepicker({
                datesDisabled: disabled_dates,
                language: currentLocale,
                format: dateFormatByLocale,
                startDate: 'now'
            });
        }

        $('#new-date').on('changeMonth', function (ev) {
            disabled_dates=['09/01/2016','09/02/2016','09/03/2016','09/04/2016','09/05/2016'];
            applyDatePickerToElement();
        });
    });
</script>
```

This code, at load applies the date picker to the element, and gives it disabledDates of 8/12, 8/13 and 8/14.  Then when you change the month, it should apply new disabled dates to the element.

I'd like the disabled dates option of the datepicker to update when I fire the changeMonth event.  So when the changeMonth event is fired I can do an AJAX call to get a list of disabled dates for that month.

Building and applying a list of disabled dates going past a few months is not an option, needs to be a month by month basis.

Comment: Looks like a few other people [have had the same issue](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=datesDisabled%20). The only solution I've seen is to remove and reinitialize the datepicker

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I will look over each of those posts.  Googled bootstrap datapicker disabled dates and did not get that page.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: No problem, hope you come right